# How do I log myself out of a frozen nx-based session?

Tags: 9.10, logout, nx

I have a nx-based session that I want killed. Can I do it via SSH?

[image: Session I want killed]

In this session, I can't click on anything or use my keyboard. However, the time in the menu bar is still updating.

I can disconnect the nx session by going to the NX Session administrator, and clicking on "disconnect session", but when I log back in again, the same screenshot usually appears (sometimes the menu bar at the top doesn't appear, and the disconnect session confirmation and the greyness where gnome-do ought to appear is absent).

I assume I have to totally log myself out, and then do a clean login again. Can I do this via SSH, or by going to the physical computer and logging in there (both of which are working fine)?

I tried in a separate SSH session the following:

```
$ dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed .

$ qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.logout -1 -1 -1
Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed:
/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

In NX session administrator you can try to remove the session files and start a new session. Anyways, if you ssh to the machine and restart NXServer, next time you login you'll have a new clean session. (`sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --restart`)

Comment: First approach didn't change anything. With respect to the second approach, do I need sudo/root?

Comment: yes, you need to sudo (corrected answer)